# InaccessibleWSDLException in my log files but everything works fine. What's wrong?

Tags: web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x

I'm deploying a web application which accesses some remote web services via jax-ws in a WebLogic container. Before a web service call I see theese messages on WebLogic's console

```
Aug 30, 2011 6:48:21 PM weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.policy.advertisementimpl.AdvertisementHelperImplregisterExtension WARNING: Registering oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.addressing.AddressingExtensionRegistry extension failed; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.addressing.AddressingExtensionRegistry
Aug 30, 2011 6:48:21 PM weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate addWsdlDefinitionFeature SEVERE: Failed to create WsdlDefinitionFeature for wsdl location: http://192.168.192.80:19100/acme/ws/FooBarService?wsdl, error: com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException, message: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.
```

which makes me think there's an issue with the webservice client code, but the webservice works fine despite the errors. I'm creating the webservice client with this code

```
FooBarService service = new FooBarService(
       new URL("http://192.168.192.80:19100/acme/ws/FooBarService?wsdl"), 
       new QName("http://www.acme.com/acmews", "FooBarService"));
FooBarServiceSoap port = service.getFooBarServiceSoap();
```

What do those error messages mean and should I worry about them?

Comment: Do you have some of your own exceptions specified in the WSDL for your service?

Comment: nope, the WSDL does not specify exceptions

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I've read somewhere the problem is weblogic not having the JRF components but I can't modify the server to include them due to company policy...

Comment: nope, never figured it out and moved to other project not involving SOAP a long time ago, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Create the folder classes inside WEB-INF, so create the folder META-INF inside classes.
The struture will be: WEB-INF/classes/META-INF.

Put the file jax-ws-catalog.xml into META-INF.

Put the file file.wsdl into META-INF.

The file jax-ws-catalog.xml must contain:

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system"><system systemId="http://localhost/wsdl/file.wsdl" uri="file.wsdl"/></catalog>
```

Now, it's you must change the address to http://localhost/wsdl/file.wsdl in your service class.

When the system look for the wsdl at http://localhost/wsdl/file.wsdl, it will be redirected to local file.